# Passing data from RecyclerView adapter to activity returns null

Tags: android

I know I am not the first to ask this ,but in this unfortunately I couldn't find the root.  I am trying to pass the selected adapter position to new activity of onclick function,But in my case when I receive the data in activity always shows null.

I tried many ways and also tried Stackoverflow solution for the simpler problems.

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        myAlarms myAlarms = myAlarmsdata.get(position);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CreateAlarm.class);
                        intent.putExtra("mSelectedId",myAlarms.getALARM_ID());
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You clicked " +position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

CreateAlarm.class

```
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        String id = extra.getString("mSelectedId");
```

I know it's not a big deal but I couldn't solve it .
can anyone tell me were I did the mistakes.

Comment: Have you logged `myAlarms.getALARM_ID()` to make sure that's the correct value before you try to send it?

Comment: yes ,It's right @BrianYencho

Comment: And its actually a `String` and not an `int` or `long`?

Comment: myAlarms.getALARM_ID() is an integer value @BrianYencho

Comment: That's your problem then. You need to use either `getIntent().getIntExtra(...)`  or `getIntent().getExtras().getInt(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `myAlarms.getALARM_ID()` is actually an `int` you need to use either `getIntent().getIntExtra(...)` or `getIntent().getExtras().getInt(...)`.